# How to structure a daily habit tracking app

Tags: django

### Background

I'm a personal trainer and trying to build an app that tracks whether or not my clients are working on their daily habits (and bugs them about it at a chosen time every day). I'd love to hear if any of you all have ideas on how to structure this as I'm new to both Django and coding in general.

### Models

I currently have two models: `Habits` and `Checks`.

`Habits` represent "What are you working on improving?" and have a ForeignKey to a user.
`Checks` represent "Did you complete your habit today?" and have a ForeignKey to a habit.

### Current status

There is a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626004/11420600) where you create all the Checks for a Habit based on it's end date, but I'm trying to structure this with an indefinite end date because, as a coach, then I can show hard data when someone isn't making progress. Though I am still willing to accept that maybe this app would work better if habits had deadlines.

I wrote a custom manage.py script that Heroku runs automatically at the same time every day, but that doesn't scale with users' individual time zones. I run it manually on my local computer.

I originally tried getting it to work with Celery but that did not go well on my Windows machine.

Should I push the script out a day or week in advance and hide the days that are in the future?
Should I avoid the script and just create a year's worth of rows and hope they don't want to track it for more than a year?
Is there a better option?

### Help requested

The two issues I'm having at this point:

- How can I have a Check created for each day? Is there a better way than what I've done already?
- How can I make the timezone for each day relative to the user?

Comment: You would need to save timezone information for each user, do you have anything that could be used for this?

Comment: Regarding the Checks - the user enters data on the app when they complete a check?

Comment: I don't have anything for saving a user's timezone, but I can look into that. Thank you.

For the checks, the user basically says, "Yes, I did my homework," which marks it as completed for that particular day.